# Rewrite URL in SEO url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My site has URL like this

**[www.abc.com/search?service=computer](http://www.abc.com/search?service=computer)**

I want

**[www.abc.com/service/computer](http://www.abc.com/service/computer)**

Tried htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ search.php?type=$1&service=$2
```

Thanks, Please help me to write this URL in SEO URL

Comment: Please do share your htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ search.php?type=$1&service=$2

Answer (score 2):

Please keep your htaccess file inside root folder/directory and try following rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  search?$1=$2 [L]
```